# How to properly escape # character in a makefile?

Tags: c, bash, makefile, terminal

I am learning about makefiles and for trying things out I wrote a makefile containing this text below:

```
blah: blah.o
        cc blah.o -o blah
blah.o: blah.c
        cc -c blah.c -o blah.o
blah.c:
        echo '\#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }' > blah.c
clean:
        rm -f blah.o blah.c blah
```

Unfortunately, by entering the `make` command I got this error:

```
blah.c:1:1: error: stray ‘\’ in program
 \#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }
 ^
blah.c:1:2: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 \#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }
  ^
blah.c:1:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
 \#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }
           ^
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'blah.o' failed
make: *** [blah.o] Error 1
```

I don't really understand the error as I escaped the # character properly (as I suppose).

Comment: If you do not know how to do something on the command line there is absolutely no chance that you succeed with make. Make is an automation tool. It automates what you would do by hand. First try to generate your source file by hand, on the command line, and you'll know how to do it with make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there isn't any need to escape characters in `'`...`'` strings. They are all literal, *including* the `\` (i.e., there isn't any way to escape characters in `'`...`'` strings).  So you're getting a literal `\` before the `#` in blah.c, which prevents the C preprocessor from noticing it as a directive.

Remove the `\` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shell question, not a makefile question.  If you run the command at your shell prompt, not from a makefile, you'll see the same behavior:

```
$ echo '\#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }' > blah.c
$ cat blah.c
\#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }
```

This is simple shell quoting rules.  If you use a single quote in the shell then nothing inside the single quoted string will be interpreted by the shell.  It will be written as-is.  So, don't quote it:

```
blah.c:
    echo '#include <stdio.h>  int main(){ return 0; }' > blah.c
```

Comment: That says `blah.c:1:21: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive`. It should be `printf '#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){ return 0; }' > blah.c` for maximum portability.

Comment: Well, yeah, whether the generated string makes sense is a different question :)

Comment: It is strange, if I write   echo '#include <stdio.h> \n int main(){ return 0; }' > blah.c in the makefile it finely compiles, but if I write just    echo "Hello \n World" , the newline character is not recognized.

Comment: Double vs. single quotes.  Also you should use printf as the behavior of echo related to escaped characters is not standardized and may differ even between shells on the same system (some shells have a built-in echo)